# Unable to get the names of the website when using pattern in python

Tags: html, css, python-2.7, web-scraping

There is the error in the code when try to fetch the names from the website, but when fetching the amount then it gives the amount perfectly

Here is the code when trying to fetch the Amount of the persons:

```
import requests
import re
from pattern import web
import pandas as pd
def list_of_prices(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    dom = web.DOM(html)
    list = []
    for person in dom('.freelancer-list-item .medium.price-tag'):
        amount = person('span')
        list.append([amount[0].content if amount else 'na'])
    return list
list_of_prices('https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=1')
```

This gives the result:

```
[[u'$20<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$20<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$68<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$45<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$38<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$61<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$20<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$34<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$35<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$14<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$27<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$47<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$40<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$12<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$15<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$61<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$68<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$15<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$14<small>PER HOUR</small>'],
 [u'$25<small>PER HOUR</small>']]
```

How to remove  in this output

Here is the code which I'm trying to fetch the names:

```
import requests
import re
from pattern import web
import pandas as pd
def list_of_names(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    dom = web.DOM(html)
    list = []
    for person in dom ('.freelancer-list-item .freelancer__name crop'):
        title = person('a.link')
    list.append([title[0].content if title else 'na'])
    return list
list_of_names('https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=1')
```

But it didn't fetch the names and shows the error:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-77ae0c541f2d> in <module>()
     11     list.append([title[0].content if title else 'na'])
     12     return list
---> 13 list_of_names('https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=1')

<ipython-input-36-77ae0c541f2d> in list_of_names(url)
      9     for person in dom ('.freelancer-list-item .freelancer__name crop'):
     10         title = person('a.link')
---> 11     list.append([title[0].content if title else 'na'])
     12     return list
     13 list_of_names('https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=1')

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment
```

How to solve this error. Please Help

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Your defined `css selectors` used within second script are wrong to make it work for parsing names.

Comment: Not yet, because I don't know about the BeautifulSoap?

Comment: You code is badly indented that Is why you are getting such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with the usage of `pattern`, I suggest you try the below one. This is supposed to work:

```
import requests
from pattern import web

page_link = "https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst?page=1"

def list_of_names(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    dom = web.DOM(html)
    list_item = []
    for person in dom('.freelancer__info'):
        title = person('.link')
        list_item.append([title[0].content if title else 'na'])
    return list_item

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    print(list_of_names(page_link))
```